While loop isn't working and the program exit
Currently working on an exercise where I need to apply aggregation.
The problem is my while loop isn't working:
It is supposed to display back the menu option, after it has for the first time, and read input again and so on, but instead the program exits after one iteration.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Address{
    private:
        string registrar;
        string country;
    public:
        void set(string r, string c){
            registrar = r;
            country = c;
        }
        string getRegistrar(){
            return registrar;
        }
        string getCountry(){
            return country;
        }
};

class Ship{
    private:
        string name;
        string yearMade;
        Address *address;
    public:
        void print(){
            cout<<"Ship Name: "<< name <<endl;
            cout<<"Year Built: "<< yearMade <<endl;
            cout<<"Registered at: "<<endl<<address->getRegistrar()<<", "<<address->getCountry()<<endl;
        }
        void read(){
            string r, c;
            cout<<"<<< Enter the information of the ship >>>"<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<"Ship Name: ";
            getline(cin, name);
            cout<<"Year Built: ";
            getline(cin, yearMade);
            cout<<"The address the ship was registered:"<<endl;
            cout<<"Registrar Office: ";
            getline(cin, r);
            cout<<"Country: ";
            getline(cin, c);
            address->set(r, c);
        }
};

int main() {
    
    Ship *ship = new Ship[100];
    int option=0, total=0;
    
    while(option != 3){
        cout<<"======== MENU ========"<<endl;
        cout<<"1. Add a ship"<<endl;
        cout<<"2. Display ships"<<endl;
        cout<<"3. Exit."<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"Choose an operation => ";
        cin >> option;
        cin.ignore();
        if(option == 1){
            ship[total].read();
            total++;
        }else if(option == 2){
            cout<<"<<< Inventory of ships >>>"<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<"Total ship: "<<total<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<"==== Ship List ===="<<endl<<endl;
            for(int i=0; i<total; i++){
                ship[i].print();
            }
        }
    }
        
    return 0;
}


address member in Ship is a pointer that is never initialized/allocated. Therefore address->set(r, c); triggers undefined-behavior (which is manifested most likely as a crash in your case). But why is it a pointer at all ? It could be Address address; (and then change the relevant dereferencing from -> to .).

Hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems?r=Saves_AllUserSaves

Also you're required to post a [mcve] in your question to meet the quality policies here, remove all irrelevant code, to demonstrate the behavior.

Ship *ship = new Ship[100]; Whoever taught you to do this is not teaching you C++. and you will run into problems at the 101st ship. Use std::vector<Ship> ships and for each ship added call ships.push_back(ship);.  Also Address *address; doesn't need to be a pointer.

Why did you make address a pointer when you did not do this for name or yearMade? As a general rule, don't use pointers, and there is certainly no need for address to be a pointer.

The problem is that the address member of class Ship, is a pointer that is never allocated or initialized.
Then when you dereference it with address->... e.g. in read(), you get Undefined Behavior (UB).
When UB happens, the C++ standard explicitly makes no guarantees about how the program will behave, so there's no point in reasoning about it.
(A side note: in practice you probably encounter a crash which causes the program to exit).
You could fix this by allocating an object and initializing address with its address in Ship's constructor.
But in this case there's no reason for address to be a pointer at all.
You can simply change it to be:
Address address;

And then change all the places where you derefernce it to use . instead of ->,
e.g.:
address.set(r, c);

(instead of address->set(r, c);).
Final notes:

Instead of using a raw C array (in Ship *ship = new Ship[100];), it is recommended in C++ to use std::vector.
It's considered bad practice to use using namespace std; - see:What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?.

